# How to make listview non-scrollable when also using smoothScrollToPosition

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

I have 2 listviews in my Activity(say list1 and list2) both having same elements in it but list1's height is small and displays only 1 item at a time and list2 size is match_parent and displays every item. when i add any element in my list it adds in both the listviews at the same time.

What I want to do is, I want to make my list1 non-scrollable every time and when I click on any item of list2, list1 should grab that position and scroll till that item.

I used the following code but even after making list1

```
setScrollContainer(false);
```

it is still making my listview scrollable. However,

```
smoothScrollToPosition(true);
```

is working fine.

```
 ListView list1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inflated_ll);
 list1.setAdapter(adapter);
 list1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 list1.setScrollContainer(false);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 scanAdapter = new ScanItemAdapter();
 ListView list2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inflated_ll2);
 list2.setAdapter(scanAdapter);
 scanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int posi,long pos) {

            ListView list1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inflated_ll);
            list1.setScrollContainer(true);
            list1.smoothScrollToPosition(posi);
            list1.setScrollContainer(false);
        }

    });
```